# Use Mysql Result as Value

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I try to get a value from SQL to use in **XML** but it seems that its not passing the value on. The sql is correct and checked in **phpmyadmin**.

Please advice,

```
$result = 
full_query("
     SELECT b.value
     FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues b
     JOIN tblcustomfields a 
     ON   a.id = b.fieldid
     AND  a.fieldname = 'CID'
     AND  b.relid = '1'; 
"); 


if (isset($result))     
{ 
    $xml .=  $result; 
} 
else
{
    return array("error" => "CID is empty");    
}
```

Comment: Code and text formatting

Answer (score 0):

`full_query` is not a php standard function, so it would be great if you post the content of this function, otherwise nobody can help you.

In general you have to create a query, preferable via `PDO::prepare`. Here is a quick snippet:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE test = ?');
$stmt->execute(['test']);

return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: To clear. I know how in general make a custom connection but as this is a function in WHMCS. full_query() will rund a full MySQL query, as there is always and active connection to the DB. 

WHMCS supports other commands also, so I will try this,

Comment: Doc. says I can use PDO - so now I tried as follow, but cant get it to work and value to return. Should have the value return to $val - please advice. 

  $pdo = Capsule::connection()->getPdo();
  $val = $pdo->prepare('
  SELECT b.value
  FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues b
  JOIN tblcustomfields a 
  ON a.id = b.fieldid
  AND a.fieldname= "nr"
  AND b.relid = '$userID'; 
  '); 
        
  $val = execute();
  
  return $val->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if (isset($val))
 
{ $xml .=  $val; 
}     
 else
    {
        return array("error" => "Field is Empty");

    }